# Xcode: Code Signing Error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

How to avoid or bypass code signing error in Xcode 6 without paying for the  developers license. I changed SDKSettings.plist present in Xcode path but still getting the error 'Dependency Analysis Error: CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'. 
   Is there anything additional I have to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait until Xcode 7 (or download a beta now). That version will allow developers to install on physical devices without purchasing a license.

Comment: Tried with Beta version too, but still same problem